# Accesing json object value through variable

Tags: javascript, json, object

```
{
  "data": [{
    "data": [{
      "Part": "1.75 L ICON (Glass)",
      "ProductionCounts": 1012620
    }, {
      "Part": "1.75 L Marg Mix (PET)",
      "ProductionCounts": 1003278
    }, {
      "Part": "1.75 L Authentics (PET)",
      "ProductionCounts": 457615
    }, {
      "Part": "1.0 L Margarita Mix / PET",
      "ProductionCounts": 660982
    }, {
      "Part": "other",
      "ProductionCounts": 1571985
    }]
  }, ],
  "dateArray": ["2011-01-01", "2011-02-01", "2011-03-01", "2011-04-01", "2011-05-01", "2011-06-01", "2011-07-01", "2011-08-01", "2011-09-01", "2011-10-01", "2011-11-01"],
  "xAxis": "Part",
  "yAxis": "ProductionCounts",
  "interestingMoments": []
}
```

I want to access the value of json object. Field name of json object will be different each time I am getting the json object so I am sending the field name in xAxis and yAxis as separate.

When I am trying to access the jsonData.data[0].data[0].xAxis , it is giving me undefined instead of value. 
I can't access like this as field name will be different each time so I am trying to access it through variable jsonData.data[0].data[0].Part .

Answer (score 2):

`jsonData.data[0].data[0][jsonData.xAxis]` and `jsonData.data[0].data[0][jsonData.yAxis]`

http://jsfiddle.net/vsZkR/

Answer (score 1):

you should use json like this

```
var a = {
  "data": [{
    "data": [{
      "Part": "1.75 L ICON (Glass)",
      "ProductionCounts": 1012620
    }, {
      "Part": "1.75 L Marg Mix (PET)",
      "ProductionCounts": 1003278
    }, {
      "Part": "1.75 L Authentics (PET)",
      "ProductionCounts": 457615
    }, {
      "Part": "1.0 L Margarita Mix / PET",
      "ProductionCounts": 660982
    }, {
      "Part": "other",
      "ProductionCounts": 1571985
    }]
  }, ],
  "dateArray": ["2011-01-01", "2011-02-01", "2011-03-01", "2011-04-01", "2011-05-01", "2011-06-01", "2011-07-01", "2011-08-01", "2011-09-01", "2011-10-01", "2011-11-01"],
  "xAxis": "Part",
  "yAxis": "ProductionCounts",
  "interestingMoments": []
};

a.data[0].data[0][a.xAxis] // for access part values
a.data[0].data[0][a.yAxis]  // for acsess ProductionCounts values
```

Answer (score 0):

for xAxis, just this should work:

```
console.log( jsondata.xAxis );
```

See here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rMhA/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var data={
  "data": [{
    "data": [{
      "Part": "1.75 L ICON (Glass)",
      "ProductionCounts": 1012620
    }, {
      "Part": "1.75 L Marg Mix (PET)",
      "ProductionCounts": 1003278
    }, {
      "Part": "1.75 L Authentics (PET)",
      "ProductionCounts": 457615
    }, {
      "Part": "1.0 L Margarita Mix / PET",
      "ProductionCounts": 660982
    }, {
      "Part": "other",
      "ProductionCounts": 1571985
    }]
  }, ],
  "dateArray": ["2011-01-01", "2011-02-01", "2011-03-01", "2011-04-01", "2011-05-01", "2011-06-01", "2011-07-01", "2011-08-01", "2011-09-01", "2011-10-01", "2011-11-01"],
  "xAxis": "Part",
  "yAxis": "ProductionCounts",
  "interestingMoments": []
};
console.log(data.xAxis);
console.log(data.yAxis);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would unwrap it from the redundant "data" object.

http://jsfiddle.net/turiyag/cQNPm/

It looks cleaner afterward, and works just fine. Your JSON object also failed JSLint. Always run your code through JSLint or a similar product before posting here.

```
log("jsonData.data[0][jsonData.yAxis]: " + jsonData.data[0][jsonData.yAxis]);
```